# can't get to web api controller action with jquery ajax post

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create my first REST application with the web api in mvc4.  I have a controller set up with the HttpPost verb but for some reason when I click the link to post the xml string to the controller I get an error - "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '/api/Apply/ApplyToJob'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Apply' that matches the request."}"  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  Here's the view page...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="lnkPost">Post Data</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#lnkPost").on("click", function () {

            $.get("/TestResponse.xml", function (d) {
                $.ajax({
                    //contentType: "text/xml",
                    //dataType: "xml",
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/api/Apply/ApplyToJob",
                    data: {
                        "strXml": (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d)
                    },
                    success: function () { console.log('success'); }
                });
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

and here's the controller.

```
public class ApplyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ApplyToJob")]
    public string ApplyToJob(string strXml)
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just post to /api/Apply

Comment: Also, you may want to do some additional reading, as the approach you are taking isn't really RESTFUL.

Comment: I assume you mean because the method isn't named Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your action's parameter like below:

`public string ApplyToJob([FromBody]string strXml)`

This is because without this `FromBody` attribute, the string parameter is expected to come from the Uri. Since you do not have it in the Uri the action selection is failing.

Also, looking at your client code, shouldn't you set the appropriate content type header in your request?

*Edited*:

You can modify your javascript to like below and see if it works:

```
$.ajax({    contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            type: "post",
            url: "/api/values",
            data: "your raw xml data here",
            success: function () { console.log('success'); }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you.  Adding the [FromBody] did let it get to my action, but strXml is coming through as null.  As for the content type header, I've been trying all kinds of things to get this to work so that's why some of the code was commented out.

Comment: WebApi depends on the content-type header to enable finding the right formatter to deserialize the body. Make sure to have the right one and you should see a non-null value.

Comment: I uncommented the top two lines so that it's setting the contentType to text/xml and the dataType to xml however it's still coming through null.  Do you know if I need to set this to something else?  Also, is there a way to specify that the controller action just receives a string without giving it a variable name (strXml)?  The reason I ask is that we're trying to tie into LinkedIn's api and I don't know that the xml they will be posting to us will have a variable name like my example does.

Comment: I have now edited the above post with the jquery example. The deserialization doesn't depend on the name of the action parameter, but the type. If you are looking to just read the post request content as a string, you could remove the parameter from the action and just do `string requestData = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`...so here you would be not going through formatters for deserialization and would be reading the body just as a string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with await and when I tried putting that code into my Post method I get an error expecting a semicolon and it highlights the word Request.  I did some googling and it looks like await was introduced with VS2012.  I'm on 2010.  Soooo, is there another way to read the content without using await?  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I found that I can get the content by instead using string requestData = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result  Thanks for your help!